# Anybody tested Zuul 2.0.0-rc2 and Websocket

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-zuul

Has anybody tested Zuul 2.0.0-rc.2?

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.netflix.zuul/zuul-core/2.0.0-rc.2

Would I be able to do websocket with it? And if so, what would it take to integrate with Spring cloud?